# How to delete a collision modifier on blender 2.8?

Tags: modifiers

I don't know if I'm missing something or is really obvious, but I can't find how to delete an added collision modifier from a sphere.

[image]

Comment: Just click on 'Collision' button again (same you've used to create it). Once created, the button has a cross X on it to indicate it will be removed if clicked.

Comment: Thank you, so obvious and I didn't see it. Can you add this as an answer and I'll mark it as solved?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove physics element, just click again on the button you've used to add it.

[image]

You can notice that once added, the original icon is replaced by a cross *'X'* which indicate it could be removed.